# Why does array === array equal true in PHP?

Tags: php

In php `===` is the identical comparison operator i.e. checks if two variables have equal values and are of the same type. But why `array("asdf") === array("asdf")` returns true? I guess both of these create new arrays with same contents(please correct me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: `array("asdf") === array("asdf")` returns true because the two arrays being compared:

1. have the same key/value pairs,
2. each of the same types, and
3. in the exact same order.

That's what `array() === array()` means.

**Good Read**

[**Array Operators**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

Answer (score 2):

Equal `$a == $b` TRUE if `$a` is equal to `$b` after type juggling.

> 2 == "2"

Identical `$a === $b` TRUE if `$a` is equal to `$b`, and they are of the same type.

> array("asdf") === array("asdf")

Not equal `$a != $b` TRUE if `$a` is not equal to `$b` after type juggling.

> 2 != "3"

Not equal `$a <> $b` TRUE if `$a` is not equal to `$b` after type juggling.

> 2 <> "3"

Not identical `$a !== $b` TRUE if `$a` is not equal to `$b`, or they are not of the same type.

> array("asdf") !== "asdf"

Less than `$a < $b` TRUE if `$a` is strictly less than `$b`.

> 99 < 100

Greater than `$a > $b` TRUE if `$a` is strictly greater than `$b`.

> 100 > 99

Less than or equal to `$a <= $b` TRUE if `$a` is less than or equal to `$b`.

> 0.32 <= 0.54

Greater than or equal to `$a >= $b` TRUE if `$a` is greater than or equal to `$b`.

> 2 >= 2

Read this [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) about comparison operators in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer

> $a === $b     Identity    TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs
>   in the same order and of the same types.

[Php Manual-Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

Comment: I see... missed that.  I'm kind of a newbie myself. ;)